# how does static modifier works in c#

Tags: c#, oop, static

i recently started studying c# and something i dont have very clear is what does `static` mean and how it behaves.

For example if a have a `static` method , i know that to use that method i need to call upon the `class` and not the instance  of the object but i really dont knwow the reason that gives that behavior.
On the other side for the propierties of the `class` if they are `static` i am not very sure how they are modified and how they behave

Comment: A static property/field of a class is present exactly once irrespective of the number of objects you created, an instance property/field is present once per created object.

Comment: Make sure you really know and understand the difference between a class and an/its instance(s). That's sth I often see beginners in OOP struggling with. If you get that, the explanation is simple: `static` are a method/property of the class - hence singleton, kinda like "scoped/namespaced globals", and non static belong to each instance

Comment: I've answers with few links highlighting the parts that are relevant to your question. Please let us know if this is clarifies things.

Comment: @tymtam yes the info was very useful, thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Please note that C# static is different from static in c++.*

From [Static Classes and Static Class Members (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members):

> **Static Member**
>
> The static member is callable on a class even when no instance of the class has been created. The static member is always accessed by the class name, not the instance name. Only one copy of a static member exists, regardless of how many instances of the class are created. Static methods and properties cannot access non-static fields and events in their containing type, and they cannot access an instance variable of any object unless it's explicitly passed in a method parameter.

and later:

> Two common uses of static fields are to keep a count of the number of objects that have been instantiated, or to store a value that must be shared among all instances.

The article also has an example of a static property:

> ```
> public static int SizeOfGasTank
> {
> get
>    {
>       return 15;
>    }
> }
> ```

I recommend reading the whole [Static Classes and Static Class Members (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members).

There also is [Static Constructors (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-constructors) which is worth reading as well because static constructors are important to understand, even if they are not used that often.

Please note that there also is [using static](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-static) directive, which is something completely different.

## How they work

*How* may mean many things so I'm not sure what exactly you're asking about, but this paragraph, again from [Static Classes and Static Class Members (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members) provides the answer to *how technically do static methods work?*:

> A call to a static method generates a call instruction in Microsoft intermediate language (MSIL), whereas a call to an instance method generates a callvirt instruction, which also checks for null object references. However, most of the time the performance difference between the two is not significant.